# Spin and orbital components of angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

[image]From what I have gathered, angular momentum in a system can be calculated about any point. However, I am having trouble grasping this, and below I suggest an imaginary situation where I try to apply this.

Imagine a rod of mass $m$ and length $D$ that hangs from a hinge that allows it to rotate. At its lowest point, it is struck by a bullet of mass $m$ as well that travels at a velocity $v_0$. I want to calculate the rod's resulting angular speed using the conservation of angular momentum about different points. I can easily calculate the conservation of angular momentum around the axis of rotation, but I am having trouble calculating it about other points.

The problem I am proposing is the continuation to the following: [About what point is angular momentum conserved?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326680/)

I would be very thankful if someone could provide an answer or correct me where I am wrong.

In the image below, the rod's resulting angular velocity is calculated using its angular momentum about its hinge (point A). If we were to calculate its angular velocity about its center of mass (point C), we should get the same result. Keep in mind that when calculating the angular momentum about the COM, we have to add the orbital component to the spin component.

If the rod were unhinged, as in the linked discussion, we could easily calculte the velocity of the COM using the conservation of angular momentum. But in this example this is no the case. Using the obtained angular velocity, we can calculate the linear speed of the COM, and plug it into the orbital component. When solving for the angular velocity, we should get the same result as before, but that is not what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot provides an external constraint force which fixes the rod. When you choose your reference point to be at point C, this external force exerts nonzero external torque, so angular momentum is not conserved.

Comment: Angular momentum should still be conserved, even if there is a hinge, since the force applied by the hinge is parallel to the direction of the rod, therefore the torque applied by the hinge is 0. What isn't conserved is linear momentum.

Comment: @Pablo:  The force from the hinge is not necessarily parallel to the direction of the rod.  You can see this by going back to your original derivation, with the origin at the hinge, and calculating the total *linear* momentum immediately before & after the collision.  You'll find that the horizontal momentum has decreased, which means that the hinge exerted a force in the horizontal direction.